# Sending contract's source code to deployed contract in order to deploy it

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, compilation, factory

I am writing a factory contract in solidity.
I want to be able to add some more contracts to be deployed by the factory after it has been deployed.

I thought sending the contract's source code to my factory. Stock it in a mapping with a custom key.
Then using a contract's function with the key in order to deploy a new contract from the new type.
Is it only possible please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with source code, because the contract would have no way to compile that code.

But you *can* do it with compiled bytecode:

```
bytes memory bytecode = ...;
assembly {
    contractAddress := create(value, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode))
}
```